# Why wont this if statement work? I may be blind but I can't find out why it wont work

Tags: python

```
input("Welcome to this calculator, press ENTER to continue")

operation = input("Type one : Add  Subtract  Multiply  Divide   ");
firstNumber = input("Type the first number you want to " + operation + "   ");
secondNumber = input("Type the second number   ");

if operation == "add" or "Add":
    finalNumber = int(firstNumber) + int(secondNumber); finalNumberString = str(finalNumber); newOperation = "adding "
elif operation == "multiply" or "Muptiply":
    finalNumber = int(firstNumber) * int(secondNumber); finalNumberString = str(finalNumber); newOperation = "multiplying "
else:
    print("Not Yet Implemented")

print("Your result of " + newOperation + firstNumber + " to " + secondNumber + " was " + finalNumberString)
```

When I run the script and try to multiply, it ends up adding them and prints "adding" instead of "multiplying"

```
Welcome to this calculator, press ENTER to continue
Type one : Add  Subtract  Multiply  Divide   Multiply
Type the first number you want to Multiply   10 
Type the second number   5
Your result of adding 10 to 5 was 15
```

Comment: For one; you misspelled "Multiply" in your second case `elif operation == "multiply" or "Muptiply":`

Comment: It's because `and` and `or` don't work that way.  Your expression is read `(operation == "add")  or  "Add"`, and since the string "Add" is always true, the if will always be taken.  Use `if operation.lower() == "add":`.

Comment: `if operation == "add" or "Add":` is not the same as `if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":` - you probably want the later

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al this link fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I change

```
if operation == "add" or "Add":    and    elif operation == "multiply" or "Muptiply":
```

to

```
if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":    and   elif operation == "multiply" or operation == "Multiply":
```

Comment: Since this is the solution given in the proposed duplicate, there's no need to add a separate answer here. The way Stack Overflow works, we try to select a single canonical instance of each question, answer it as thoroughly as possible, and then direct other people with the same question there -- that way the effort of building the best possible answers (and vetting/improving/editing those answers) gets concentrated rather than spread out.